# How to generate dynamic content via mod_perl handler in Template::Toolkit?

Tags: perl, nginx, cgi, mod-perl, template-toolkit

I was just trying to use `Template::Toolkit` perl module on my centos to generate dynamic web content. [This tutorial](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Web.html#section_Dynamic_Content_Generation_Via_Apache_Mod_Perl_Handler), and the one given on cpan site, is made to bind mod_perl with Apache. I'm using nginx on my centos. i tried allot, but I'm less into server things, so failed each time. 
Can anyone help me to integrate mod_perl with nginx? Or is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mod_perl is an Apache module. It cannot be used with nginx.

To use Template::Toolkit with nginx, you will need to implement a web application some other way. Probably the most straightforward way of doing this will be to write it as a [Plack](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack) application; this will allow it to be run as a HTTP or FastCGI server that nginx can proxy requests to.

Comment: One could always write a directive to use the `tpage` tool that ships with Template [described here](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/index.html). But that's probably questionable.